# Como mazimizar la distancia minima de un punto a varios puntos en Minizinc?

Tags: optimización, complejidad

Debo proponer un modelo para el siguiente problema con Minizinc:

La región EcoReg tiene un problema serio de
depósito de basuras, y ha decidido construir un nuevo relleno dentro de sus fronteras. Como es natural,
cada ciudad dentro de la región está en alerta y presionando para que el sitio no quede cerca de su ciudad. Por tal razón, los administradores de la región
quieren encontrar un sitio que quede lo más lejos posible de la ciudad m´as cercana. Los administradores
han decidido medir la distancia entre dos ciudades
con la métrica Manhattan la cual define la distancia
entre dos puntos como la distancia en el eje X más la
distancia en el eje Y.
La región se representa como un cuadrado perfecto
de Nkm por Nkm. Identificamos la esquina al suroccidente de la región con la posición (0,0). En este
sistema, las ciudades están situadas sobre las intersecciones. Por ejemplo si N = 10, una entrada posible
sería:

| Ciudad | Este | Norte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 9 |
| 5 | 0 | 6 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 9 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 |

Para ir de la esquina suroccidental a la ciudad 10
hay que recorrer 5 kms al este y 2 kms al norte.
El relleno no tiene que ser localizado en una
intersección de la grilla correspondiente a la ciudad.
Puede ser ubicado en cualquier punto dentro de los
límites de la ciudad.

Una instancia podria ser:

- Entrada:

  n=10;
  m=2;
  ciudades=[|3, 8,
  |4,0|];
- Salida:

  Este:10, Norte: 4.5 y Distancia 10.5

Realice el siguiente modelo:

```
% Parametros
int: n; % tamaño de la region
int: m; % cantidad de ciudades
array[1..m,1..2] of int: ciudades;

% Variables 
var int: f;
var int: x;
var int: y;

% Restricciones
constraint x >= 0;
constraint y >= 0;
constraint x <= n;
constraint y <= n;
constraint forall (i in 1..m) (ciudades[i,1] != x /\       ciudades[i,2] != y); 

% Declacion de funciones
function var int: valAbs(var int: x) = if x >= 0 then x else -x     endif;
      
function var int: manhattan(var int: x1, var int: y1, 
                          var int: x2, var int: y2) =
      valAbs(x2 - x1) + valAbs(y2 - y1);
      
% Objetivo
array[int] of var int: dist =     [manhattan(x,y,ciudades[i,1],ciudades[i,2]) | i in 1..m];
constraint f = min(dist);
solve maximize f;

output [% "Solucion: ", show(dist),"\n", "P(",show(x),",",show(y), ")\n",%"Rango = ", show(rango),"\n","F = ", show(f),"\n",];
```

Requiero hacer que el modelo retorene una solucion para "x" e "y" float, lo he intentado pero el modelo me dice que las operaciones estan sobre un valor infinito.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los planteamientos? _No todos pueden ver las imágenes_.

Comment: Voy a modificar el enunciado directamente con el texto

Comment: ya agregue el plantemiento

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y esto es un lenguaje en particular? porque la pregunta no tiene etiqueta de lenguaje (si no existe, la creamos).

Comment: Voy a hacer el recorrido de bienvenida. Y si, esta implantado wn un lenguaje  llamado Minizinc y la etiqueta no existe aún, tampoco  existe la etiqueta de programación  por restricciones (ese es el paradigma del lenguaje).